# Changing the font of the document title and author names in markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I'm using rmarkdown to produce a pdf document with conversion done either in RStudio or by using the `render()` function in R. Can anyone give me some pointers for changing the size, colour etc. of the font used for the document title and author names? I have made a lot of progress with things like changing the overall font and so on by editing the front matter in the document but I am completely lost on this one. Please bear in mind that I do not speak LaTeX very well...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never I guess.

Changing individual parts of the default rmarkdown layout does not work without making use of a little bit of LaTeX.

First of all, here is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Lord of the Rings"
author: "J. R. R. Tolkien"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{fetamont}
  - \newcommand*\eiadfamily{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{eiad}\selectfont}
  - \newcommand{\mytitle}{\eiadfamily}
  - \newcommand{\myauthor}{\ffmfamily \textcolor{blue}}
  - \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\centering\huge\eiadfamily}
  - \preauthor{\centering\large\myauthor}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


## Chapter 1
````

In this approach, we do not need to include a custom TeX template. We make use of the fact that rmarkdown uses the LaTeX package called `titling` to create the document header. The documentation can be found [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling?lang=de).

Using the commands `\pretitle` and `\preauthor` of that package we can redefine the style of the header. The defaults that are used by rmarkdown are (see [code on github](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default.tex))

```
\pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\centering\huge}
\preauthor{\centering\large\emph}
```

**Now to the code. What did we do:**

We imported two packages, `xcolor` and `fetamont`. The first one is needed to make use of colors and the latter one is a package containing a font we aim to use.

With the next three lines we define 3 new commands. The first one (`\eiadfamily`) is used to set the font family to be `eiad`.
The other two (`\myauthor`, `\mytitle`) just combine the setting of a font and a color.

Lastly we redefine `\preauthor` and `\pretitle` to

```
\pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\centering\huge\eiadfamily}
\preauthor{\centering\large\myauthor}
```

(Notice that I deleted `\emph` from `\preauthor` since an oblique version of the ffm font family is not available.)

Here is the result:

[image]

**An overview of available fonts can be found at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/.**

Comment: Fantastic answer. Worth pointing out that you can simply use `- \newcommand*\eiadfamily{\setmainfont{eiad}}` if the font is already installed in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a CSS code chunk solved it for me:

```
{css echo=FALSE}
.author {color: black; font-family: cursive }
.title {color: black; font-family: cursive }
```